# How to query a PostgresSql json database with Nodejs and PG

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, pg

I have a postgreSQL database that stores all changes to table in json format, new_val and old_val
It looks like this

new_val

```
  {"id":6,"id_item_type":7,"id_contact_as_producer":2,"id_contact_as_owner": 2,"comment":"3213","id_item_status":1,"imageurl":null,"id_station":2,"audit_id":null}";"
```

old_val

```
{"id":6,"id_item_type":7,"id_contact_as_producer":2,"id_contact_as_owner":2,"comment":"3213","id_item_status":1,"imageurl":null,"id_station":null,"audit_id":null}"
```

I can query this easily in pgadmin with the sql command

```
SELECT * FROM audit.history WHERE new_val ->> 'id_item_type' = '7'
```

But when I try to query it from nodejs with PG it just hangs. I think it is because PG gets it input as a string

```
var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM audit.history WHERE new_val ->> 'id_item_type' = '7'', 
        function (err, result) {
            done();
    });
```

So my question is basically, how can I use query the db from PG in Node to give me the same result?

Comment: Try instead: `client.query('SELECT * FROM audit.history WHERE new_val ->> id_item_type = 7',` (some quotes removed, not needed and wrong syntax)

Comment: It did not work, it seems that only id_item_type and 7 can be string and the rest not but then PG won't accept it.